# 500 Internal Server Error when trying to access .ashx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, iis-7

I have recently ran into a problem that would not allow me to use DELETE and PUT requests into my .ashx file, so I added the proper verbs in order to allow that access.  Now I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error.  Here is my web.config for the handlers:

```
<handlers>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <remove name="svc-Integrated" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="svc-Integrated" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="OwssvrHandler" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\isapi\owssvr.dll" path="/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="JSONHandlerFactory" path="*.json" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ReportViewerWebPart" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebPart.axd" type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.WebParts.WebPartHttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.WebParts, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControl" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <add name="ashxhandler" path="*.ashx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" validate="True" />   
</handlers>
```

Here is the httpHandlers:

```
<httpHandlers>
<add path="*.ashx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" validate="True" />
    </httpHandlers>
```

Any ideas?  I already went to IIS 7, went to Request Filtering, added .ashx file extension, set it to true and then in the HTTP Verbs section I added DELETE, POST, GET, HEADER, PUT.

EDIT:

Here is my .ashx file:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="jQueryUploadTest.Upload" %>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace jQueryUploadTest {

    public class Upload : IHttpHandler {
        public class FilesStatus
        {/*
            public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public int size { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string delete_url { get; set; }
            public string delete_type { get; set; }
            public string error { get; set; }
            public string progress { get; set; }
           */

            private string m_thumbnail_url;
            private string m_name;
            private string m_url;
            private int m_size;
            private string m_type;
            private string m_delete_url;
            private string m_delete_type;
            private string m_error;
            private string m_progress;

            public string thumbnail_url { get { return m_thumbnail_url; } set { m_thumbnail_url = value; } }
            public string name { get { return m_name; } set { m_name = value; } }
            public string url { get { return m_url; } set { m_url = value; } }
            public int size { get { return m_size; } set { m_size = value; } }
            public string type { get { return m_type; } set { m_type = value; } }
            public string delete_url { get { return m_delete_url; } set { m_delete_url = value; } }
            public string delete_type { get { return m_delete_type; } set { m_delete_type = value; } }
            public string error { get { return m_error; } set { m_error = value; } }
            public string progress { get { return m_progress; } set { m_progress = value; } }
        }
        private readonly JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        private string ingestPath;
        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
        public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
            //var r = context.Response;
            ingestPath = @"C:\temp\ingest\";

            context.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-cache");

            HandleMethod(context);
        }

        private void HandleMethod (HttpContext context) {
            switch (context.Request.HttpMethod) {
                case "HEAD":
                case "GET":
                    ServeFile(context);
                    break;

                case "POST":
                    UploadFile(context);
                    break;

                case "DELETE":
                    DeleteFile(context);
                    break;

                default:
                    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 405;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void DeleteFile (HttpContext context) {
            string filePath = ingestPath + context.Request["f"];
            if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }
        }

        private void UploadFile (HttpContext context) {
            List<FilesStatus> statuses = new List<FilesStatus>();
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection headers = context.Request.Headers;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headers["X-File-Name"])) {
                UploadWholeFile(context, statuses);
            } else {
                UploadPartialFile(headers["X-File-Name"], context, statuses);
            }


            WriteJsonIframeSafe(context, statuses);
        }

        private void UploadPartialFile (string fileName, HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count != 1) throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Attempt to upload chunked file containing more than one fragment per request");
            Stream inputStream = context.Request.Files[0].InputStream;
            string fullName = ingestPath + Path.GetFileName(fileName);

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int l = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                while (l > 0) {
                    fs.Write(buffer,0,l);
                    l = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                }
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
            }
            FilesStatus MyFileStatus = new FilesStatus();
            MyFileStatus.thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + fileName;
            MyFileStatus.url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName;
            MyFileStatus.name = fileName;
            MyFileStatus.size = (int)(new FileInfo(fullName)).Length;
            MyFileStatus.type = "image/png";
            MyFileStatus.delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName;
            MyFileStatus.delete_type = "DELETE";
            MyFileStatus.progress = "1.0";

          /*  {
                thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + fileName,
                url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName,
                name = fileName,
                size = (int)(new FileInfo(fullName)).Length,
                type = "image/png",
                delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName,
                delete_type = "DELETE",
                progress = "1.0"
            };
            */
            statuses.Add(MyFileStatus);

        }

        private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) {
            for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++) {
                HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[i];
                file.SaveAs(ingestPath + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                FilesStatus MyFileStatus = new FilesStatus();
                MyFileStatus.thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + fileName;
                MyFileStatus.url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName;
                MyFileStatus.name = fileName;
                MyFileStatus.size = file.ContentLength;
                MyFileStatus.type = "image/png";
                MyFileStatus.delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName;
                MyFileStatus.delete_type = "DELETE";
                MyFileStatus.progress = "1.0";
                statuses.Add(MyFileStatus);
            }
        }

        private void WriteJsonIframeSafe(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) {
            context.Response.AddHeader("Vary", "Accept");
            try {
                if (context.Request["HTTP_ACCEPT"].Contains("application/json")) {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                } else {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                }
            } catch {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            }

            string jsonObj = js.Serialize(statuses.ToArray());
            context.Response.Write(jsonObj);
        }

        private void ServeFile (HttpContext context) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["f"])) ListCurrentFiles(context);
            else DeliverFile(context);
        }

        private void DeliverFile (HttpContext context) {
            string filePath = ingestPath + context.Request["f"];
            if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment, filename=\"" + context.Request["f"] + "\"");
            } else {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            }
        }

        private void ListCurrentFiles (HttpContext context) {
            List<FilesStatus> files = new List<FilesStatus>();

            string[] names = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\ingest", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            foreach (string name in names) {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(name);
                FilesStatus MyFileStatus = new FilesStatus();
                MyFileStatus.thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + f.Name;
                MyFileStatus.url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + f.Name;
                MyFileStatus.name = f.Name;
                MyFileStatus.size = (int)f.Length;
                MyFileStatus.type = "image/png";
                MyFileStatus.delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + f.Name;
                MyFileStatus.delete_type = "DELETE";

                files.Add(MyFileStatus);
                /*files.Add(new FilesStatus
                {
                    thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + f.Name,
                    url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + f.Name,
                    name = f.Name,
                    size = (int)f.Length,
                    type = "image/png",
                    delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + f.Name,
                    delete_type = "DELETE"
                });*/
            }

            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline, filename=\"files.json\"");
            string jsonObj = js.Serialize(files.ToArray());
            context.Response.Write(jsonObj);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://nbcddmsps01:87/_layouts/IrvineCompany.SharePoint.CLM/aspx/Upload.ashx?f=test.txt
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

I ONLY got this error AFTER i added verbs to my web.config so I could call DELETE and PUT requests into the httphandler

Comment: You should install ELMAH into your application so you can get decent unhandled error logging, as Jordao said it's most likely an unhandled error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error normally means that your handler code is throwing an exception that is not being handled by your code. Take a look.

Comment: I have uploaded the code and error in there if you could take a look, thanks!